# Spring AnnotationConfigApplicationContext: constructor vs register/refresh method?

Tags: spring

The [AnnotationConfigApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html) class has the following:

```
public AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Class<?>... componentClasses)

Create a new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext, deriving bean definitions from
the given component classes and automatically refreshing the context.

Parameters:
componentClasses - one or more component classes — for example, @Configuration classes
```

and

```
public void register(Class<?>... componentClasses)

Register one or more component classes to be processed.
Note that AbstractApplicationContext.refresh() must be called in order
for the context to fully process the new classes.

Specified by:
register in interface AnnotationConfigRegistry

Parameters:
componentClasses - one or more component classes — for example, @Configuration classes

See Also:
scan(String...)
AbstractApplicationContext.refresh()
```

Observe both, the *constructor* and the `register` method work with `Class<?>... componentClasses` and the latter requires to call the `refresh` method. Through [the source code that version of the constructor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java#L90) does the `register` and `refresh` methods call

Therefore, when is mandatory use **directly** the `register` and `refresh` methods over the constructor version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is based if profiles are involved or not. If they are not involved does not matter what approach is used - it according with your preferences - it such as:

- `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` constructor for `Class...` and `String...`
- `register`
- `scan`

But if profiles are involved and is need it use the Spring API such as:

```
ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("jdbc", "mysql");
```

Therefore is mandatory use `register` (or `scan`) with the `refresh` method.

Is **crucial** define the profiles **before** to call *direct* or *indirectly* the `refresh` method - otherwise if is declared **after** of the `refresh` method - they are ignored. It even if they appear listed through:

```
for(String activeProfile : ctx.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles()) {
    System.out.println(" " + activeProfile);
}
```

**Observation**:

About *indirectly*: it is when the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`'s constructor for `Class...` and `String...` parameters is used. Internally in the constructor is called the `refresh` method.